# Which operators constructed from 10d gamma matrices commute with $SO(1,2)\times SO(3)\times SO(3)$?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, lie-groups, mp.mathematical-physics, clifford-algebras

In the paper [Supersymmetric Boundary Conditions in N=4 Super Yang-Mills Theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0804.2902.pdf) by Gaiotto and Witten, an in-depth analysis of boundary conditions in N=4 Super Yang-Mills in four dimensions in performed.

My main interest is the set of operators given in equation (2.7). It is claimed that **the action of** **$W=SO(1,2)\times SO(3)\times SO(3)$ commutes with the operators**
$$
B_0=\Gamma_{456789}\\B_1=\Gamma_{3456}\\B_2=\Gamma_{3789},
$$
(where the subscripts on right-hand-sides indicate completely antisymmetrized products of 10D gamma matrices. Note that $SO(1,2)$ acts on the indices $012$, and the two $SO(3)$ groups act on $456$ and $789$ respectively.)

How does one prove that this is true?

Comment: x-posted on physics.SE: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/396226/84967